# Find min and max 'Rainfall' for each month and corresponding month with date

Tags: mysql

I have a table (test) with 7 columns as below:

```
stcode   | year | month | day  | Rainfall| min_Temp| max_Temp|
+-------------+------+-------+------+---------+----
| chennai| 2013 |     1 |    1 |      10 | 23      | 28      |     
| chennai| 2013 |     1 |   12 |      08 | 13      | 23      |      
| chennai| 2013 |     1 |   18 |      04 | 15      | 25      |     
| chennai| 2013 |     2 |   11 |      11 | 10      | 30      |
| chennai| 2013 |     2 |   23 |      18 | 12      | 22      |
| Madurai| 2013 |     1 |   08 |      24 | 14      | 24      |
| Madurai| 2013 |     1 |   19 |      09 | 19      | 29      |
| Madurai| 2013 |     1 |   01 |      22 | 11      | 21      |
| Trichy | 2013 |     2 |   17 |      06 | 16      | 26      | 
| Trichy | 2013 |     2 |   21 |      16 | 26      | 36      |
| Trichy | 2013 |     2 |   27 |      26 | 18      | 28      |
```

... so on
    I'm trying to get min and max for 'rainfall','min_temp','max_temp' and corresponding dates and group by year, month
    and I use a query like this

```
mysql> select * from test
    -> where min_temp in(select min(min_temp) from test)
    -> or min_temp in (select max(min_temp) from test)
    -> or max_temp in (select min(max_temp) from test)
    -> or max_temp in (select max(max_temp) from test)
    -> group by stcode,year,month,day
    -> order by stcode;
```

I am trying to get min and max for rainfall, mintemp and maxtemp for each month and the corresponding dates

Comment: Can you show expected/sample ouput?

Comment: Just store the date.

Comment: I take the **"and corresponding dates"** specification to mean that you want to return the "day" value on which the minimum rainfall occurrred, the "day" value on which the maximum rainfall occurred. The query in my answer returns a single "day" value for each.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is set based logic... So Assuming I understand requirements to:

1) Return the min/max temp for any stcode and all dates that have that min/max temp for a stcode.

so first get a set that meets your requested conditions.  Min and max temp for each month at each stcode; as in:

```
SELECT stcode, month, min(min_temp) as minTemp, max(min_temp) as maxTemp
FROM test
GROUP BY strCode, month
```

Irrespective of year and day.

Now if you want to know what day(s) this occurred on just join it back tot he original set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT stcode, month, min(min_temp) as minTemp, max(min_temp) as maxTemp
    FROM test
    GROUP BY strCode, month) B
 on A.stcode = B.stCode 
 and A.MinTemp=B.MinTemp 
 and A.MaxTemp=B.MaxTemp 
 and A.Month=B.Month
```

And all records matching that min/max temp and stcode will return.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (stcode VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,date DATE NOT NULL
 ,Rainfall INT NOT NULL
 ,min_Temp INT NOT NULL
 ,max_Temp INT NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY(stcode,date)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('chennai','2013-01-01',10,23,28),
 ('chennai','2013-01-12',08,13,23),
 ('chennai','2013-01-18',04,15,25),
 ('chennai','2013-02-11',11,10,30),
 ('chennai','2013-02-23',18,12,22),
 ('Madurai','2013-01-08',24,14,24),
 ('Madurai','2013-01-19',09,19,29),
 ('Madurai','2013-01-01',22,11,21),
 ('Trichy ','2013-02-17',06,16,26),
 ('Trichy ','2013-02-21',16,26,36),
 ('Trichy ','2013-02-27',26,18,28);

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
 | stcode  | date       | Rainfall | min_Temp | max_Temp |
 +---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
 | chennai | 2013-01-01 |       10 |       23 |       28 |
 | chennai | 2013-01-12 |        8 |       13 |       23 |
 | chennai | 2013-01-18 |        4 |       15 |       25 |
 | chennai | 2013-02-11 |       11 |       10 |       30 |
 | chennai | 2013-02-23 |       18 |       12 |       22 |
 | Madurai | 2013-01-01 |       22 |       11 |       21 |
 | Madurai | 2013-01-08 |       24 |       14 |       24 |
 | Madurai | 2013-01-19 |        9 |       19 |       29 |
 | Trichy  | 2013-02-17 |        6 |       16 |       26 |
 | Trichy  | 2013-02-21 |       16 |       26 |       36 |
 | Trichy  | 2013-02-27 |       26 |       18 |       28 |
 +---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+

 SELECT stcode
      , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')
      , SUM(rainfall)
      , MIN(min_temp)
      , MAX(max_temp) 
   FROM my_table 
  GROUP 
     BY stcode
      , DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m');
 +---------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
 | stcode  | DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') | SUM(rainfall) | MIN(min_temp) | MAX(max_temp) |
 +---------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
 | chennai | 2013-01                   |            22 |            13 |            28 |
 | chennai | 2013-02                   |            29 |            10 |            30 |
 | Madurai | 2013-01                   |            55 |            11 |            29 |
 | Trichy  | 2013-02                   |            48 |            16 |            36 |
 +---------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+

 SELECT x.*
   FROM my_table x
   JOIN  
      ( SELECT stcode,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') yearmonth, MIN(rainfall) min_rainfall FROM my_table GROUP BY stcode,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')) y
     ON y.stcode = x.stcode
    AND y.yearmonth = DATE_FORMAT(x.date,'%Y-%m') 
    AND y.min_rainfall = x.rainfall;

 +---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
 | stcode  | date       | Rainfall | min_Temp | max_Temp |
 +---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
 | chennai | 2013-01-18 |        4 |       15 |       25 |
 | chennai | 2013-02-11 |       11 |       10 |       30 |
 | Madurai | 2013-01-19 |        9 |       19 |       29 |
 | Trichy  | 2013-02-17 |        6 |       16 |       26 |
 +---------+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: @Stawberry: I think the specification of **"and corresponding dates"**  could be taken to mean that OP wants to return the "day" value for a row on which one of the min/max values occurred. (But, I may have read more "into" that specification than was warranted.)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the min/max for a given month is straightforward. More problematic is returning the day on which that max or min value occurred.

To get the results on a single row, something like this:

```
SELECT m.stcode
     , m.year
     , m.month
     , m.min_rainfall
     , MIN(IF(d.rainfall=m.min_rainfall,d.day,NULL)) AS min_rainfall_day
     , m.max_rainfall
     , MIN(IF(d.rainfall=m.max_rainfall,d.day,NULL)) AS max_rainfall_day
     , m.min_min_temp
     , MIN(IF(d.min_temp=m.min_min_temp,d.day,NULL)) AS min_min_temp_day
     , m.max_min_temp
     , MIN(IF(d.min_temp=m.max_min_temp,d.day,NULL)) AS max_min_temp_day
     , m.min_max_temp
     , MIN(IF(d.max_temp=m.min_max_temp,d.day,NULL)) AS min_max_temp_day
     , m.max_max_temp
     , MIN(IF(d.max_temp=m.max_max_temp,d.day,NULL)) AS max_max_temp_day
  FROM ( SELECT r.stcode
              , r.year
              , r.month
              , MIN(r.rainfall) AS min_rainfall
              , MAX(r.rainfall) AS max_rainfall
              , MIN(r.min_temp) AS min_min_temp
              , MAX(r.min_temp) AS max_min_temp
              , MIN(r.max_temp) AS min_max_temp
              , MAX(r.max_temp) AS max_max_temp
           FROM test r
          GROUP
             BY r.stcode
              , r.year
              , r.month
       ) m
  JOIN test d
       ON  d.stcode = m.stcode
       AND d.year   = m.year
       AND d.month  = m.month
 GROUP
    BY m.stcode
     , m.year
     , m.month
```

Note that if there is more than one day (for a given stcode and month) that have the same "highest" max_temp, this query will return just first "day" that occurred.

For example, there could be multiple days in a month that had "0" rainfall. If you want to return all those day values, you could use GROUP_CONCAT() function in place of the outermost MIN(), to return a comma separated list of day values that had a matching value.

```
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(d.rainfall=m.min_rainfall,d.day,NULL)) AS min_rainfall_day_list
```

---

Comment: @Strawberry: The inline view `m` is straightforward, gets the min/max values for the month. The ugly part is getting the "day" on which each of those min/max values occurred. One approach is a join back to the original table, getting all the rows that have a matching min/max value, and then picking out the day value. We could join to that original table six times, but that would be even uglier. We just put the conditional test in an expression in the SELECT list... essentially asking the question: was this day one of days that a particular min/max value occurred?